# Xcode - how to use a test plan for a scheme (convert button is missing)

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to use test plans for the scheme in one of my libraries. In a previous library I created, I selected the "Convert to use Test Plans..." button in the scheme editor, but in my current project, this button is missing. In addition, after creating a test plan, it does not show up in Product > Test Plan in the menu bar.

[image]

In a different project that I created, the "Convert to use Test Plans..." button exists:

[image: scheme editor with convert to use test plans button]

Why is this button missing in one of my projects? What do I need to do so that I can add a test plan to my scheme?

Comment: The fact that it's a _library_ is interesting. You might want to tell us more about that.

Comment: https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/ReadLine

Comment: I don't understand why you're enclosing the word scheme in quotes. Packages can have schemes. You're looking right at them in the images. And both of the above examples are packages.

Comment: Here's a package with a test plan: https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPI/tree/master/Tests

Comment: Well, the other one (ReadLine) is not a valid package (because it has no version tag) so I can't compare the two qua packages.

Comment: A package doesn't need a version tag or even have to be under source control at all for you to add it as a dependency to a project or another package, which means these things are not required for it to be considered a valid package. You can depend on a package in your local file system. For example: `.package(name: "SpotifyAPI", path: "/Users/pschorn/Swift/Libraries/SpotifyAPI")`.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/PackageDescription.md#user-content-methods-3:~:text=%2F%2F%2F%20Add%20a%20dependency%20to%20a,static%20func%20package(path%3A%20String)%20%2D%3E%20Package.Dependency)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the above question 'Why is the **Convert to use Test Plans** missing in one of my projects?

I also had this issue and boiled it down to the following:
It depends on if there is this element in your MyProject.xcscheme file:

```
<TestPlans>
</TestPlans>
```

If you have this empty element in there, the button won't be shown.

This might happen like this:

- create a new project
- open the app scheme -> the button is there
- now use the convert button and create a xctestplan
- take a look at the changes in your git client

[image]

- we see that the  element has been removed and the  elements has been added. Ok for that.
- now remove the testplan in the schema -> the convert button does not appear again. This is because now we have the empty  element. Appearently Xcode doesn't react correctly - I think this is a bug.

Workaround: remove the

```
<TestPlans>
</TestPlans>
```

and bring back the

```
<Testables>
</Testables>
```

I use VS Code for this because the xcschema is in a subfolder of the .xcodeproj which is easier to handle with VS Code

UPDATE: seems like it's fine to just delete the  element